# Get a list of Woocommerce products and the amount of times they were ordered in a week

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I've tried many different ways but none of them seem to work for me. I've tried doing a WP_Query like this:

```php
$query = new WP_Query([
    'post_type' => 'shop_order',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => '-1',
    'year' => date("Y"),
    'monthnum' => date("m"),
    'w' => date("W"),
]);

foreach ($query->posts as $order) {
  $product = $order->get_product_from_item($order->ID);

  echo $product->get_title();
  // Now I need the variation name and the amount of times the clientes orders this
}
```

Basically, I want to get the orders of an item showing the variation and the amount of times this was ordered in the current week.

Something like this:

`[product name] | [variation] | [total amount ordered by all customers]`

Does anyone has an idea of what I need to do in order to achieve this?